# Send canvas as image with discord webhook js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, discord

I am trying to send canvas through discord webhook, But discord webhook requires image url.

I tried this

```js
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", webHookURL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            'content': message,
            'username':'AI',
              "embeds": [{
    "image": {
      "url": canvos.toDataURL()
    }
```

but discord returns bad request 400.

Whats the right way to send canvas as image to discord??

Comment: this might help? https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/9ip99a/can_you_upload_images_directly_with_a_webhook/

Comment: @NickSlash didnt help

Comment: can you provide an example that does work using a static image? the `url` parameter in your `image` makes me think its an actual url (allowing the server to download the image itself from that url) and not actual image data.

Comment: @NickSlash this is a working example


```js
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", webHookURL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
            'content': message,
            'username':'AI',
              "embeds": [{
    "image": {
      "url": "https://discord.com/assets/ee7c382d9257652a88c8f7b7f22a994d.png"
    }
```


but i dont have image url, the ``url`` is image data as you said, i am trying to send raw image, or upload canvas to a random website and get its url